# Filter many X|Y coordinates from 2 inputs by distance

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering, coordinates, jsfiddle

I want to filter many coordinates by distances, but i cant calculate every element of two dimensional table with another one. I have done changing format from text into two dimensional array where each element is a coord which has X and Y.
Can't explain it all but i have fiddle project where it is clearly shown.

Result what I want to get is a list of coords from textfield1 which their distances arent highter than 5 for each coord from textfield2

Please check out: https://jsfiddle.net/Ashayas/9c7mjts4/

```js
console.log("==== 1 ====");
//Get inputs
var coords1 = document.getElementById("coord1").value.split(" ");
var coords2 = document.getElementById("coord2").value.split(" ");
console.log(coords1);
console.log(coords2);

console.log("==== 2 ====");
//Make them X and Y
var coords1_intoXY = [];
for (var i = 0; i < coords1.length; i++) {
  coords1_intoXY[i] = coords1[i].split("|");
}
var coords2_intoXY = [];
for (var i = 0; i < coords2.length; i++) {
  coords2_intoXY[i] = coords2[i].split("|");
}
console.log(coords1_intoXY);
console.log(coords2_intoXY);

//Now combine all x|y and put into new array, after that sort and get result
//I dont know is that good thinking, maybe there is another way to achieve result
/*
var beforesort = [];
for (var i = 0; i < originalContent.length; i++) {
  paste7[i] = originalContent[i].join(" ").split(splitCharacter).filter(x => !unwantedContent.includes(x));
}
      function compare(coords1,coords2){
  const coords3 = [];
  
    let result;
  
  coords1.forEach((e1,i)=>coords2.forEach(e2=>{
    
         if(e1.length > 1 && e2.length){
            result = compare(e1,e2);
         }else if(e1 !== e2 ){
            result = false
         }else{
            result = true
         }
    })
  )
  
  return result
  
}
*/

x1 = 10
y1 = 10

x2 = 1
y2 = 1

example = Math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
console.log("Example = " + example);

function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  a = Math.abs(Number(x1 - x2));
  b = Math.abs(Number(y1 - y2));
  c = Math.sqrt((a * a) + (b * b));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Program sort coordinates X|Y from inputs. Result is a list of coordinates from input1 which their distances between second input coords arent highter than the value from input 3 (for example "5")
<br>
<br> Two inputs for coordinates X|Y
<br>
<textarea id="coord1">3|1 5|5 10|10</textarea>
<textarea id="coord2">9|1 1|1</textarea>
<br> Sort by max distance
<br>
<input value="5" id="coord3">
<br>

<br>
<textarea id="result">Result</textarea>
<br>
<button id="show">Show</button>

<br>
<br> EXAMPLE:
<br>
<br> We have "3|1 5|5 10|10" inside coord1
<br> We have "9|1 1|1" inside coord2
<br>
<br> Program calculate distance between coords
<br> 3|1 and 9|1 = 6
<br> 3|1 and 1|1 = 2
<br> 5|5 and 9|1 = 5.65 ~ 6
<br> 5|5 and 1|1 = 5.65 ~ 6
<br> 10|10 and 9|1 = 9.05 ~ 9
<br> 10|10 and 1|1 = 12.72 ~ 13
<br>
<br> And the result should looks like this:
<br> 3|1
<br> Other coords are higter than 5 distance in any case so we skip them
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

[>>>IMAGE HOW IT LOOKS<<<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EsT6.png)

I need it for school project and want to learn for future so comments between code would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want a list of coords from textfield1 which their distances arent highter than 5 for ALL coords from textfield2, or just any coords from textfield 2. Either way, the code is very similar.

You want to filter out values not meeting some criteria, so we start with the method `filter`

`coords1_intoXY.filter()`

So what is the criteria? I'll assume the distance must be lower than 5 to all numbers on textfield 2, so we will need `every`

`coords1_intoXY.filter(coords1 => coords2_intoXY.every())`

Note that if you want coords that are in range of any of the coords in textfield 2, just replace `every` for `some`

Now, as oliver said, we calculate the distance.

```js
var coords1_intoXY = [["3", "1"], ["5", "5"], ["10", "10"]];
var coords2_intoXY = [["9", "1"], ["1", "1"]];

let answer = coords1_intoXY.filter(coords1 => coords2_intoXY.some(coords2 => {
  let x = Number(coords1[0]) - Number(coords2[0])
  let y = Number(coords1[1]) - Number(coords2[1])
  return Math.hypot(x, y) < 5
}))

console.log(...answer.map(coords => coords.join('|')));
```

For the last part, display as you wish

```
return answer.map(coords => coords.join('|'));
```

Comment: It works! That is what i have tried to achieve. Thanks iagowp and Olivier!

Comment: Another question. Do You know some method to work on large amout of coords?
For example when i want sort 10000 and 50000 program stop responding and gives result after long period of time (not always). I have tried make offline version of html with this app but the problem is still the same. Program seems to stop responding after copy/paste coords and result after calculation can be copied only from console log. It is problem with RAM? Can I make this porgram to use graphic card somehow? (this isnt requirement for project but im just interesting)

Comment: It will take a long time, I mean, your time complexity is O(NxM). I have no idea how to use graphic card or stuff like that. To make it more likely you get a result, you can split the first array into smaller arrays, and do then once at a time.

Comment: I have found solution. Just make program to work in background, another one is web workers. That's all :P

Last question. Do You know how to sort coords1 by amount of coords2 in that specified range? First do normal result with coords and then sort them by distance? (General how to add function calculating amount of that coords2 in coords1 range example: https://i.imgur.com/PYzCJ8q.png)

Or maybe I should try to rewrite code to work like this:
1. Calculate distance between every coord.
2. Delete higher than "5"
3. Sort array by coord
4. Return number of the same coords

???

Comment: You might want to write a new question, as it has deviated a lot from the original one. Anyways, I'd use a `map` on `coords1_intoXY` where I'd add the number of coords on `coords2_intoXY ` that are on the range, and then filter the results where the third value is 0, then sort using sort method. The join would need to be changed to only join the first 2 values also.